# How to catch view errors in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Where can I register a handler in Rails 3 that can catch view errors? There is a class of error that Rails raises that we wish to handle and silence instead of logging as FATAL.

(These are not errors in our code, rather errors caused by the client closing the connection before the page has finished rendering, and Rails/unicorn attempting to write to a broken pipe.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will `rescue_from` work for you? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

You can conceivably rescue (and silence) your particular subclass of `ActionView::TemplateError`

Comment: It actually did - try this on your ApplicationController   rescue_from 'ActionView::TemplateError' do |ex|
    render :text => ex.message
end

Comment: Ah, I've discovered that there's an interaction here with the fact that we have streaming turned on. With streaming turned on there is not way to not log view errors as fatal

Comment: I.e. rescue_from will not catch view errors if you have streaming turned on